# Operating a RAID controller (Ultra ATA 133) with two HDs: one 133, the other 100

Tags: raid

In this setup, will the RAID controller (I'm going to use the one integrated in the [Gigabyte GA-7DXR+](http://www.gigabyte.de/products/product-page.aspx?pid=1303#sp)) run both disks in Ultra-ATA 100?

Or will it run the disks each with their native speeds (133/100) ?
From my understanding of RAID, it should run the disks at their native speed.

I'm going to run it with RAID 1.

Comment: With Raid it is always best to use matched hard drives, same model and firmware revision, not a must but would be wise. Intersecting question, one would assume Yes, I would contact Gigabyte support and ask them.

Answer (score 1):

A raid1 will (almost) never run faster than the slowest disk. One exception is if your raid controller is smart enough to distribute read requests. The wikipedia has a good article about raid.